# What is the use of queryExecution in spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have got to know about variable called queryExecution on a dataframe object and found below output in console . But it is not sure how it can be helpful .Please find the output in the console.

```
scala> df.queryExecution
res5: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext#QueryExecution =
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Project [_1#0 AS ID#2,_2#1 AS Token4#3]
 LocalRelation [_1#0,_2#1], [[1,a],[2,b]]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
ID: int, Token4: string
Project [_1#0 AS ID#2,_2#1 AS Token4#3]
 LocalRelation [_1#0,_2#1], [[1,a],[2,b]]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [ID#2,Token4#3], [[1,a],[2,b]]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [ID#2,Token4#3], [[1,a],[2,b]]

Code Generation: true
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To implement Spark SQL, Spark implements an extensible optimizer, called `Catalyst`, based on functional programming constructs in Scala.

At its core, Catalyst contains a general library for representing trees and applying rules to manipulate them.

On top of this framework are built specific libraries to relational query processing (e.g., expressions, logical query plans), and several sets of rules that handle different phases of query execution: analysis, logical optimization, physical planning, and code generation to compile parts of queries to Java bytecode.

Thus the `queryExecution` is an integral part of a Dataset/DataFrame which represents the query execution that will create and transform your data.

We mainly use it to debug and optimize transformation.

You can read more about the introduction to the Catalyst in the following blog post [Deep Dive into Spark SQL’s Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html) and also in Mastering Apache Spark by @JacekLaskowski :

- [Query Execution](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-debugging-execution.html). [WIP]
- [Debuggig query execution](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-query-execution.html). [WIP]

Comment: thanks for your reply @eliasah   .. I too have got same resources sharing this question in here. But I was wondering how I can optimize join operation for very bigger datasets which may vary from 1billion records or more. This is the reason I started exploring how spark dataframe works?

Comment: @eliasah there are any way to take Physical Plan and reconstruct an execution plan to documentation? I'm trying splitting the plan with regular expression and put in order to reconstruct a readable plan. Can I access the DAG object to take all cycle with all applied operations?